# Eth could work with Kintex US without DDR option enable?

Tags: fpga, ethernet, microblaze, evb

I have a custom board which i'm trying to test a ping test using Eth from Microblaze master with no DDR Support.

Technically , to check if this option is actually exists , i took an EVB - KCU105. And as part of my testing, i have used a stable example project(Configure Microblaze Design) , &remove DDR checkbox from it and try to run example design that include Microblaze on Kintex Ultrascale KCU105 EVB.

After exporting bitstream into XSDK(2018.3) I have used lwIP Echo Server template within the xsdk

in order to try pinging to other LAN point.

it seems that it doesn't work .

So i tried one more time to figure out if i did something wrong, &i tried to use the same project - with DDR , then it works.

So my question is, is there any option to run ETH function with microblaze with no DDR on?

Thanks .

Amir .

Answer (score 0):

Your question is:

*So my question is, is there any option to run ETH function with microblaze with no DDR on?*

**Answer**:

In principle, **Yes**. And I remember I have come across such project in the past where I was trying *not* to have DDR. And I remember this [post](https://forum.digilentinc.com/topic/19361-fpga-ethernet-without-ddr-memory/?sortby=date) provided me good pointers.